# What alcoholic drinks are popular with out alcohol?

Tags: flavor, alcohol

I don't drink alcohol do to a Psychiatric drug.

There has to be some alcoholic drinks that taste okay with out alcohol.

What drinks are popular to get with out alcohol?

Comment: Not to be facetious, "coke" from "rum and coke" ...one of the key ingredients and flavouring in most of the alcoholic drinks is flavour of the alcoholic component (e.g. the rum in a rum and coke). You can often get flavouring compounds made to taste like the said ingredients, which you could add to your drink. There are a huge range of "mocktails" that are designed to be like cocktails, but without the alcohol.

Comment: @bob1 what is the most complex alcoholic drink then surely something has to taste okay.

Comment: https://www.townandcountrymag.com/leisure/drinks/how-to/g785/best-mocktail-recipes/

Answer (score 3):

I'd google "virgin cocktails" or "mocktails"

There are more and more non alcoholic recipes out there.

Most mocktails are variations on regular cocktails, using different juices and aromatics or bitters to simulate the alcohol taste and flavors

For example, a [virgin pina colada](https://www.thespruceeats.com/virgin-pina-colada-recipe-2097115) more or less just omit the rhum.